# Is there documentation that describes how each part of the Inno Setup WizardForm is connected?

Tags: inno-setup

I am having a very difficult time finding any documentation about how the various parts of the Inno Setup Wizardform are hooked together.

Using various answers here on StackOVerflow I have gathered some information but most of the time these are inferences rather and I'm not confident I really have a good grasp.

I have looked at the online help available at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php and specifically the section on [Support Classes Reference](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses) but it just gives me a list of all the parts of the wizard form. I really would like more information about how things like the InstallingPage and the InnerPage relate. I've looked through the listing of topics as well and nothing appears to relate to the question I have.

I'm just having a very difficult time grasping how all of those various parts hook together and where each part is in a hierarchy either visual or logical.

I guess I could go look at the source code for Inno Setup but I thought it'd be worth asking here first before diving into an unfamiliar code base in a language I've only been poking at for two days. If that is my only recourse, I guess I'll have to.

Comment: There is no such document as far as I know. I could show you how to generate the visual control parent hierarchy directly from setup script if that's what you want. Would that be enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I  would like more information about how things like the InstallingPage and the InnerPage relate.

No, WizardForm internals are not documented. 
You might read the source.

A code search reveals that the search terms do not occur that often.

- https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/search?q=InnerPage
- https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/search?q=InstallingPage

This is the source for the [Wizard itself](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Wizard.pas) and it's [form](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Wizard.dfm.txt).

The pages are hooked together via [`RegisterExistingPage()`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Wizard.pas?q=Setup#L774).

Comment: This was the path I ended up taking. I found the linked form description and in conjunction with the link I provided was able to figure out how things were connected to achieve the result I was looking for.